# Смена текущего каталога из дочернего процесса

Tags: ruby, процесс

Подскажите, возможно ли сменить директорию из руби-скрипта в окне консоли, из которой он был вызван?

Что то вроде:

```
# test.rb
`cd /new/dir`
```

Желаемый результат:

```
$ pwd
/my/test/dir
$ ruby test.rb && pwd
/new/dir
```

Comment: Нет. Вы можете сменить директорию для процесса ruby, но после выхода из оного все вернется "на круги своя".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**краткий ответ**: это невозможно.

---

**чуть более длинный ответ** (с некоторыми упрощениями и без кучи оговорок):

текущий каталог — это свойство процесса.

свойство это наследуется «дочерними» процессами от «родительского».

когда вы в оболочке выполняете, например, команду `ruby ...`, оболочка запускает «дочерний« процесс (делает *fork*), который уже и «загружает в себя» бинарный файл `/usr/bin/ruby`.

этот «дочерний» процесс (под управлением загруженного бинарника), конечно, может изменить **своё** свойство — текущий каталог, и даже передать его «по наследству потомкам». но на «родительский» процесс он никакого влияния оказать не может.

Answer (score 1):

> сменить директорию в окне консоли

можно, если устроит создание дочернего шелла

```
# chdir.rb
Dir.chdir ARGV[0]
exec "bash"

$ pwd
/home/me/dir1/dir2
$ ruby chdir.rb ..
$ pwd
/home/me/dir1
```