# Как перейти в другой каталог в командной строке с помощью скрипта на Python'е?

Tags: python, python-3.x, командная-строка

При открытии командной строки я нахожусь в корневом каталоге своего диска. Каким образом можно написать такой скрипт на языке Python, чтобы при открытии его из корневого каталога с помощью командной строки, командная строка меняла свой каталог на тот, который указан в скрипте?

Пытался решить эту проблему таким образом:

```
import os
os.system ( 'cd C:\\Путь_к_нужному_каталогу' )
```

Но почему-то при запуске этой программки не происходит вообще ничего, даже ошибки никакой не выдает. Что делать?

P. S. К этому вопросу ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015886/Как-выполнить-команду-в-cmd-через-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015886/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2-cmd-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-python)) я обращался, но ответа на свой вопрос там я не нашел.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена текущего каталога из дочернего процесса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435990/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: Так ошибки и нет - вы переходите в каталог, но в дочернем процессе, а после возвращения оттуда оказываетесь там же, где и были.

Comment: Короче говоря, это сделать невозможно?

Comment: да запусти новую командную строку

Comment: @eri  А вот и нет. `os.chdir('yourdir')`

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica ваш код делает не обеспечивает смену каталога в самой командной строке, только если на время выполнения скрипта

Comment: AppleScript: `tell application "Terminal" to do shell script "cd <yourpath>"`?

Answer (score 1):

Решение для систем, где есть `fcntl` модуль:

```
import pipes
import fcntl, termios

def invoke(text):
    for c in text:
        fcntl.ioctl(1, termios.TIOCSTI, c)

def change_dir(directory):
    invoke('cd ' + pipes.quote(directory) + '\n')

change_dir('./somedir')
```

Для Windows надо использовать `win32api` модуль для подобных хаков.

Если вам необязателен `Python`, а можно просто `Bash`-скрипт, то достаточно запустить его с помощью `source` или `.`.